# What's the meaning of www/whois/intoDNS for a hostname?

Tags: dns, whois, www, dedicated-server

[image: he]

when I rent a dedicated server, there have three buttons for a hostname.

www/whois/intoDNS, what's the meaning of them, what's the function they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be just useless shortcuts for common tasks which can be done to a hostname:

- The "www" link probably tries to open the hostname as a website (i.e. launches `http://HKT-TEST01`).
- The "whois" link probably tries to do a [WHOIS database](https://www.google.com/search?q=whois) lookup for the domain name.
- The "intoDNS" link probably uses the https://intodns.com website to do miscellaneous "health checks" on the domain's DNS configuration. (Some of them superfluous.)